# Sonarlint for Visual Studio C# drastically slows down build times

Tags: c#, sonarlint

We recently activated the binding between our SonarQube server and our code with SonarLint.

Since there our build times are taking 10 to 15 times than before!

Our solution contains a hundred of projects for 250,000 lines of code and after building it there are about 3000 analysis warnings.

Do you think I can speed up the build times without unbinding SonarQube?

Thanks!

Comment: How many rules are activated on your quality profile in the server?

Comment: We have 160 rules, we didn't change the default ones (for now).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can do much for now on.

Comment: :'( Too bad. Well, we will keep analyzing our code on build machines only (our developers will be very sad). Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Is there a way to analyze which specific rules are taking time?

Comment: By activating each rule one by one? Will be a very long process! ^^ By the way, I don't know if Sonar can do this itself.